# runtimeType of Lexical Closure

Tags: dart

**Code:**

```
void main(){
  print(foo().runtimeType);
}

Function foo(){
  return (){};
}
```

**Output:**

```
() => Null
```

Why is this **Null** and not **void**?

Comment: The return type of `foo` here is `Function`. You can get the behavior you expect by using a function type with a full signature that includes the return type (in this case `void`) and parameter types (in this case empty parameter list). See https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#prefer-signatures-in-function-type-annotations.  With the full signature function type it would be `void Function() foo() { return () {}; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [dart official site](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#return-values):

> All functions return a value. If no return value is specified, the statement return null; is implicitly appended to the function body.

Comment: And `void` is just a type we use to indicate that the value should not be used.